# How to use OpenStreetMap without using Mapbox?

Tags: swift, openstreetmap, mapbox

I want to use OSM(OpenStreetMap) data. but there is one way(Mapbox) to use?

If there is other solution to use OSM(OpenStreetMap) without using MapBox, that will be helpful to me.

Comment: You don't need MapBox for OSM. [Raw OSM data](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) is available for download. But that's probably not what you are looking for, is it? Please tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You can download most (all?) OSM data and use it in Apple's MapKit. I have certainly done so for feature data. Check here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Using_OpenStreetMap#Software_development

Comment: Thank you guys! I try your help. what i mean is maybe map box's pricing is expensive for me in premium. so I want to find without using mapbox. Thx

Comment: There is already a `swift` tag. There is no need to add "Swift" to the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is tagged with Swift, I'm assuming you're looking for an iOS SDK to add OpenStreetMap maps to an application. You certainly don't need Mapbox to do that - there are many libraries, of which I would recommend [WhirlyGlobe](https://github.com/mousebird/WhirlyGlobe/). There's also a [list of Maps libraries for developers on the OSM Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Apple_iOS#Libraries_for_developers).

Comment: Thanks about your recommend :) I'll try that WhirlyGlobe one day.

Comment: But When I Do tutorial in WhirlyGlobe, I saw map box code or something, is that whirlyglobe don't use map box API?

Comment: @tmcw You saved me. It's like a month that I look for an alternative to `MKMapView` to be able to use vector maps. My Problem is that G.P.S. route tracking is very poor, and I want to use some kind of restriction on read locations so not having them jump into a building when accuracy is very poor. Usually I read a 65 meters horizontal accuracy, resulting in a  really shacking `MKPolyline`. As far as I understood I could easily snap to street a `CLLocation` or at least within the vector limits of the buildings right?