# How can we access our OSRM instance when creating an app in Swift?

Tags: swift, openstreetmap, osrm

We are running our own OSM tile server and OSRM.  It is pretty straight forward to set URLs for both when accessing them in Java/Android (OSMDroid) and Web (Leaflet).  Is there a comparable open source / free package or library (not Mapbox) out there for an Apple app?  Or suggestion for resources to help us understand how to access our OSRM in MapKit?  We can see how to add OSM tiles to MapKit, but are struggling to understand how to get routing directions from our OSRM instance.  Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use OpenStreetMap without using Mapbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912434/how-to-use-openstreetmap-without-using-mapbox)

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't.  We've definitely looked at that list.  I've edited my question to be more clear that we want something open source (and free) like OSMDroid and Leaflet.  Please note that our main issue is that we want to get routing directions from our own OSRM instance.  None of the options in the Distance table seem to answer that (to include Mapbox).  For Android and Web, there are libraries that cater to those running their own OSM tile server and OSRM.